# How do i get the select tag value with codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

how do i get the select tag value, i am using the syntax below but not working.

Controller

```
 'role' => $this->input->post('rol'));
```

View
these are the options in my select tag

```
<select name="rol">
 <option value="Employee">Employee</option> 
 <option value="HR">HR</option>
 <option value="Student">Student</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you share your ajax function and your html page also, so all user can understand what is not working?

Comment: There is never any benefit to repeating the option tag's text as its `value` -- just omit the value declaration.  Everything will still work as expected with javascripting and form submissions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$role = $this->input->post("rol");
```

Answer (score 0):

how did you write your **selection** **dropdown** list!did you take it as i **posted** below?

```
<select name="rol" id="pos_select" class="form_input">
    <option value="Employee">Employee </option>
    <option value="HR">HR</option>
   <option value="Student">Student</option>
</select>
$role = $this->input->post("rol");
```

Comment: yes mam, i just dont know how to post it here. it keeps disappear.

Comment: @vincentmarcvillafuerte  which method are you using GET or POST in your view?

Comment: im using ajax and its post mam,

Comment: so did you get selected value in your ajax call?and can you share your ajax function?

Answer (score 0):

Just try it to post like below:

```
  <form action="your_controller_action" method="POST">
    <select name="rol" id="pos_select" class="form_input">
      <option value="Employee">Employee </option>
      <option value="HR">HR</option>
      <option value="Student">Student</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post it">
  </form>
```

Then in your controller:

```
  public function youControllerAction() {
    if( $this->input->post) {
      echo $this->input->post("rol");
   }
  }
```

You will get the selected option value.

Answer (score 0):

**put this code in view. Only you have to call controller function in action. In this example I am getting option values from database**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url()."main/project_filter_skills"; ?>">
<select  class="demo-default " id="skilltags" name="skilltags[]" data-placeholder="Choose skills">
   <option value="">Choose skills</option>
   <?php foreach ($all_skill_tags as $skilltags) {  ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $skilltags->secondCat_id;?>">
   <?php echo $skilltags->secondCat_title;?>
   </option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
</form>
```

**now put this in modal or controller to get the vlaue**

```
$skilltags= $this->input->post('skilltags');
```